# Reordering msbuild task causes resources to be omitted from assembly

Tags: .net, build, msbuild, resources, resx

I'm attempting to integrate a custom task into my ASP.Net application. After the addition of my task none of the `resx` files get included in the build which causes things to fail.

Here is the order of the working build, with little csproj modifications:

```
CoreResGen
PreComputeCompileTypeScript
CompileTypeScript
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute
CoreCompile
_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal
GetTypeScriptCopyToOutputDirectoryItems
_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory
_CopyAppConfigFile
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory
TypescriptDefinitionCompile
```

I'd like my task `TypescriptDefinitionCompile` to be run after `CopyFilesToOutputDirectory` but before `CompileTypeScript`.

So i insert the following code into the project file:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="msbuild.TypeScriptDefinitions" AssemblyFile="..." />
<Target Name="TypescriptDefinitionCompile" 
        AfterTargets="AfterBuild" 
        DependsOnTargets="CoreCompile;CopyFilesToOutputDirectory">
  <Message Text="Compiling Typescript Definitions"/>
  <TypeScriptDefinitions AssemblyPath="..." OutputPath="..." />
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
  <CompileTypeScriptDependsOn>
    TypescriptDefinitionCompile;
  </CompileTypeScriptDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I've found the attributes `AfterTargets` and `BeforeTargets` to be generally useless, it doesn't actually re-order the execution of the build that I can see and then my task complains that it can't find the assembly or the typescript build runs too early. For that reason I'm using `DependsOnTargets` and overriding the `CompileTypeScriptDependsOn` group which is specified in the VS typescript targets file.

The result of the build order now, is:

```
CoreResGen
CoreCompile
GetTypeScriptCopyToOutputDirectoryItems
_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory
_CopyAppConfigFile
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory
TypescriptDefinitionCompile
CompileTypeScript
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute
```

Right away I can see that the `GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute` task is in the wrong place, so I added a `CoreCompileDependsOn` to get it to run before `CoreCompile`, that fixed the order of that task but still the `resx` files are getting excluded from the resulting assembly. I can see that the `.resources` files are being emitted to `\obj` in the `CoreResGen` task, and `CoreResGen` still runs before `CoreCompile`, so why are the resources not being included?

I should also note that *everything* works so far with this configuration except for the resources being omitted. In fact, I was using this for about a week before I even noticed.